# Create Spring Boot microservice that accepts a given Json?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

So the question: i have the following Json:
{
"type": "ipv4",
"value": "1.2.3.4",
"firstSeen": "2020-07-10 15:00:00.000",
"totalCount": 8
}
i need to create a spring boot microservice from it ,with the following restrictions:

1. TotalCount cannot be less than 0 and cannot be more than 100.
2. firstSeen date should ALWAYS be converted to ISO 8601 format. The user can enter the date
   in any string format. Return error if it is not well formed.
   Expose the following RESTful APIs
3. Create a new record (as shown above, id auto-generated)
4. Get record by value

as this is my first time working with microservice,i can not understand this problem,is there anyone can help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a basic Spring Boot project using Spring Initializer, if you are using Intellij you can use this link as reference https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/your-first-spring-application.html#create-new-spring-boot-project.

Then add a new controller method which accepts a Json Request. Since you are trying to create a new record, I suggest you use POST method. Json Request will accept the 4 input parameters you mentioned. This is very basic and you should be able to find it in pretty much any Spring boot tutorial online. you can refer for example https://dzone.com/articles/simple-spring-boot-post

This Json Request can have validator annotations which check for the criteria you give. For example you can have @Size(min=0, max=100, message="TotalCount cannot be less than 0 and cannot be more than 100"). https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-size-length-column-differences

For date you might need to write a custom validator to check the specific format you want. For creating a record I guess you mean adding it to database. here you can configure your database using the yaml file, again there are lot of online resources on how to configure a Database in your spring boot project. https://blog.tericcabrel.com/write-custom-validator-for-body-request-in-spring-boot/

Since its your first time, it might take a while to figure out various details but I assure you once you get a hold of it, its going to be easy.